# Given $\tau, \sigma \in L(V)$, find $\mu \in L(V)$ such that $\sigma = \mu \tau$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space and $L(V)$ is the collection of linear operators on $V$. $\tau, \sigma \in L(V)$ are given. Suppose that $\text{ker}(\tau) \subseteq \text{ker}(\sigma)$. Show that there exists a $\mu \in L(V)$ such that $\sigma = \mu \tau$. I have tried this with matrices and it does seem to work but I haven't been able to come up with a general method of constructing $\mu$. It is also easy to see that it fails if $\text{ker}(\tau) \subseteq \text{ker}(\sigma)$ does not hold. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is no norm and continuity requirement this is true even infinite dimensional case.  Define $\mu (y)=\sigma (x)$ when $y=\tau (x)$. This defines $\mu$ on the range of $\tau$. It is well defined because $ker (\tau ) \subseteq \ker (\sigma)$ There is always a subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $V=W \oplus \tau (V)$. Now taking $\mu =0$ on $W$ we can extend $\mu$ to a linear map on $V$: of $v=w+y$ with $w \in W, y \in \tau (V)$ define $\mu (v)=\mu (y)$.

Comment: Thanks! This is very clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

It's a finite-dimsionsional proof.Let $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$ be a basis of $ker(\tau)$. Then we can extend the basis to be a basis of $V$,namely $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$.

By the fundmental theoram of linear algebra,note that $\{\tau(v_{k+1}),\ldots,\tau(v_n)\}$ is independent.Therefore we can construct $\mu$ such that $\mu(\tau(v_{k+1}))=\sigma(v_{k+1}),\ldots,\mu(\tau(v_n))=\sigma(v_n)$.
Then we have done.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. This will make $\{ \tau (v_{k+1}),...,\tau (v_n)\}$ a basis for $\text{im}( \tau )$ and we take $\mu(v) = 0$ if $v \notin \text{im}(\tau )$. It seems like this proof works when $V$ is infinite-dimensional as well. We could just let $B$ be a basis for $\text{ker}( \tau )$ which will make $ \tau (B)$ a basis for $\text{im}( \tau )$, which as I understand is Kavi Rama Murthy's proof.